# how can i send message from server to client - websockets

Tags: scala, websocket, akka-http

I am successfully processing client messages/requests

```
object EchoService {

  def route: Route = path("ws-echo") {
    get {
      handleWebSocketMessages(echoService)
    }
  }

  val echoService: Flow[Message, Message, _] = Flow[Message].map {
    case TextMessage.Strict(txt) => TextMessage("ECHO: " + txt)
    case _ => TextMessage("Message type unsupported")
  }
}
```

how can i send message from server to client ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do over here? Simply pushing notifications from Server to client or something else. Take a look at this [blog](https://markatta.com/codemonkey/blog/2016/04/18/chat-with-akka-http-websockets) for inspiration.